# How to create a conditional test?

Tags: javascript, cypress

Good day everyone! I'm trying to create a conditional test in cypress but can't figure out how to do it. I have a construct that must be executed if there is an element in the DOM. If it is not, then there should be just a pass. How to implement it?

```
it("something test", () => {
    cy.get("body").then(($body) => {
      if ($body.find('button[name="button-row-add"]')) {
        cy.get('button[name="button-row-add"]').click();
        cy.get('input[name="newValue"]').type("Cypress Test String");
        cy.get('button[name="submit-dimension"]').click();
        cy.wait(500);
      }
    });

    cy.get(".table-cell").each(($el) => {
      cy.wrap($el).dblclick();
      cy.wrap("[class^=form-cell]").as("form").should("exist");
      cy.wrap("@form").get('textarea[name="value"]').type("Cypress Sell Test");
      cy.wrap("@form").get('button[aria-label="submit-button"]').click();
    });
  })
```

Comment: A conditional test seems like a bad test.

Comment: yes, I understand this. But such is the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
  if ($body.find('selector').length > 0) {
    //Element is present, Do something
  }
})
```

Comment: in cypress else is it necessary? I thought the code would just do nothing if it didn't find the element

Comment: `else` is not necessary, you can just go with the `if`. Updated my answer.